# How do I identify wether it is a male or female in the table row?

Tags: sql

i have a database called tblsignup and a table called registration.
in registration table it has colum of Id, name lastname, age, and gender.
I want to identify if the first row is a male or female

is my query correct? sorry I'm noob.

```
create function MorF (@stats int)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @stats = int
    set @stats = 0
        
    declare @gender nvarchar(50)
    set @gender = (select Gender from registration where id = 0x)
        
    if @gender = 'Male'
        begin
            set @stats = 1
        end
    else
        begin
            set @stats = 0
        end
        
    returns @stats
    
end
```

Comment: This question doesn't contain a [example] of the data.

Comment: You don't need a `@stats` parameter, but you may need an `@id` parameter to select a specific registration.

Comment: Are "Male" and (presumably) "Female" the only two options for Gender? No "null" values or "Other" (etc)?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Also you might want a [CASE expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) (SqlServer-specific link but other DBMSs have the same or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like SQL Server.  If so, I would recommend a *single statement* *scalar* function.  This simply looks like:

```
create function MorF (@id int)
returns int
as
begin
    return (select (case when gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end)
            from registration r
            where r.id = @id
           );
end;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e4908a961660ecc3cd070c2150f864ec) is a db<>fiddle.

One of the major changes is in the `WHERE` clause of the subquery.  This assumes that the parameter being passed in is the `id` of interest.  I renamed the parameter to `@id` for clarity.

Also note that your local parameter `@stats` conflicts with the parameter being passed in.  The above code just side-steps that problem by avoiding internal parameters.